# Здравствуйте, как проинициализировать пустой массив

Tags: java, массивы

Условие задачи:
Mетод должен найти максимальное число и вернуть его индекс в качестве результата. В случае, если массив пустой, вернуть -1.

```
public int indexOfMax(int[] array) {
    int indexMaxValue = 0;
    if (array != null || array.length != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[indexMaxValue] < array[i]) {
                indexMaxValue = i;
            }
        }
        return indexMaxValue;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Вот тесты:

```
@Test
void indexOfMaxTest() {
    log.info("Index max of value in array {} = {} ", victim, test.indexOfMax(victim));
    assertEquals(3, test.indexOfMax(victim));
    log.info("Index max of value in array {} = {} ", arrayEmpty, 
        test.indexOfMax(arrayEmpty));
    assertEquals(-1, test.indexOfMax(arrayEmpty));
}
```

Вот моя инициализация:

```
private static int[] victim;
private static int[] arrayEmpty;

@BeforeAll
static void beforeAll() {
    test = new LookupArrayService();
    victim = new int[]{1, -6, 9, 10, 0};
    arrayEmpty = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
}
```

вопрос, как проинициализировать пустой массив?

Comment: `arrayEmpty = {};` ?

Comment: Пасиба, но может подскажешь, почему тест на пустой массив все равно не проходит, ну т. е он все равно не считает что он пустой и выводит actual = 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пустой массив без элементов:

```
int array[] = { };
```

Пустой массив из 3 элементов:

```
int array[] = new int[3];
```

Comment: проиницилизировать удалось, но тест на возвращение -1 все равно не проходит, может подскажешь, выдает actual 0ж

Comment: ой сорян ж* --- ;